# Accounts are not locking out after multiple 4771 Kerberos pre-authentication failure events

Tags: password, user-accounts

This seems to be the reverse problem from most things I found on the internet.

I am seeing a large number of 4771 Kerberos pre-authentication failure events being generated and the error code is 0x18.

This tells me that it is a bad password. I check the user's account and it is not locked out even though it should meet the threshold for tripping the GPO for account lockout. I run the AD Lockout tool to notice that AD lists the account of having a bad password count of 0 and the last bad password is 2 days ago. I do notice that there is some 4740 events in our environment so we are logging the events.

Ideas on why accounts are generating 4771 Kerberos pre-authentication failure events but not getting locked out or registering as a bad password with the AD Lockout tool?

```
Event Code = 4771 && Error Code = 0x18
Count = 487 in the previous 10 minutes

Event Code = 4740
Count = 0

GPO:
Enforcement Password History = 5 passwords
Account Lockout Threshold = 5 invalid logon attempts
```